# How do I label forms fields in bootstrap using the layout grid

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I found an awesome way to layout form fields using bootstraps grid system. See jsfiddle link.
http://jsfiddle.net/kUNVs/

When I place a label on the zip code field everything still looks good. But when I use the same "logic" to apply a label to the city field It sits under the zip code label. Or in the second example I have it totally hoses the layout.

So the question is, based on the example in jsfiddle above, how do I add a label to the city field and have it position above city and not zip code?

I have tried this.

```
<label for="zipcode">Zip Code</label>
<label for="city">City</label>
<div class="controls controls-row">
 <input type="text" id="zipcode" class="span1" placeholder="Zipcode"/>
 <input type="text" id="city" class="span2" placeholder="City"/>
</div>
```

and this

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
 <label for="zipcode">Zip Code</label>
 <input type="text" id="zipcode" class="span1" placeholder="Zipcode"/>
 <label for="city">City</label>
 <input type="text" id="city" class="span2" placeholder="City"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you a good start:

```
<form>
    <div class="controls controls-row">
        <label for="street">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="span3" id="street" name="street" placeholder="Street"/>
    </div>
    <div class="controls controls-row">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span2">
                <label for="zipcode">Zip</label>
                <input type="text" id="zipcode" class="span1" placeholder="Zipcode"/>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <label for="city">City</label>
                <input type="text" id="city" class="span2" placeholder="City"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

<kbd>**[Live Demo - Basic](http://jsfiddle.net/kUNVs/55/)**</kbd>

I just added a row for the zip code and city using two spans (`.span2` and a `.span4`) to separate them. If I were you I'd also update the span classes on the inputs themselves to match their container spans.

<kbd>**[Live Demo - With Input Spans](http://jsfiddle.net/kUNVs/56/)**</kbd>

Comment: Perfect. That will do it. Thanks again